# What is the path in hybrid app for files inside the www folder(local folder)?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, multi-device-hybrid-apps

What is the path in hybrid apps for android,windows and ipad for files stored inside project solution as www->data->filename.doc? I want to access these files and open them.

Comment: Use this `file:///android_asset/www/data/filename.doc` .

Comment: Thanks Jay. Any idea on windows and iOS?

Comment: How do you want to access them?

Comment: I want to open the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I think `cordova.file.applicationDirectory` is what you are after.

For example on iOS and Android I would do:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/data/filename.doc', win, fail);
```

And on Windows (8 anyway) which confused me for a while, I would do:

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Windows.Foundation.Uri(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/data/filename.doc')).done(gotControls, fail);
```

Make sure you have the two file plugins installed also:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

Hope that helps.

EDIT: I have just read this again and realised you just wanted to open the files, the above is still relevant for the file paths but I would look into using this open plugin: https://github.com/disusered/cordova-open to actually open the files, I have not tried it with a .doc file before but it will work with .pdf files.

This can be called as:

```
var open = cordova.plugins.disusered.open;
open(encodeURI(url), success, error);
```